# How would I keep a ChromeCast Chrome tab alive?

Tags: chromecast

I have a status page (a la Google Analytics) that I want to stream to my screen via ChromeCast. The problem I'm running into is that after 10 or 15 minutes, my ChromeCast cuts off the connection and goes back to the ChromeCast screen rather than continue casting from my status board. I already tried having the page refresh automatically, but apparently that's not good enough.

Ideally I just want to do this via a Chrome tab without having to create an entire application, but I'm willing to do so if necessary. I don't see anything in the docs to suggest that this is possible, though.

Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Is the screen you are casting a static one in which no UI change happens or there are elements that change on the UI?

Comment: Things could change. It's a status board, so if something happened in the app, then numbers and charts would change. The page is set to refresh every 5 minutes via Javascript, but Chromecast still cuts off the connection after about 15 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the cause is; but I think casting a tab here might be overkill, and not using it might fix your issue.

Casting a tab basically encodes what's visible into a video stream and streams it over your network to the Chromecast. This uses significant resources encoding the video on your PC, network transfer of a video stream, decoding on the Chromecast.

If the app is already web-based, it would be much better to get the Chromecast to just render it natively (this avoids encoding anything to a video stream, and removes the need for your PC to be on completely).

I'm still waiting for my Chromecast to be whitelisted so I can't test it; but I suspect it would be trivial to be able to get the Chromecast to display a "status page" natively with just a little HTML and JS on your PC to "launch" it, and a tiny wrapper for the receiver.